# Entity Framework 6 context.Database.SqlQuery<bool>

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Probably a supereasy thing to fix.

I need to make a raw SQL query to the database:

```
var blnOrders = (bool)db.Database.SqlQuery<bool>(@"SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1] WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE [Extent1].[OrderNumber] IS NOT NULL
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent2] WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE [Extent2].[OrderNumber] IS NOT NULL
    )) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]")
```

A `DbRawSqlQuery<bool>` is returned from this. Trying to convert it to a `bool` and then using the variable gives me the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<bool>' to 'bool'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong? I thought you could just cast it to a `bool`?

Checked the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907) but there's only an example using `SqlQuery<string>`.

Comment: remove this ``(bool)`` casting from start

Comment: It must be enough to call Single on DbRawSqlQuery<bool> like this

var blnOrders = (bool)db.Database.SqlQuery<bool>(@"...").Single();

Answer (score 1):

Remove the (bool) as Ehsan told you, then

```
var res = await blnOrders.SingleAsync();
```

Comment: by blnOrders.SingleAsync() you mean db.Orders.SingleAsync?

Comment: No, I mean using the blnOrders as you posted it but without (bool). SingleAsync will actually execute the query, await will make your code wait until the response is retrieved (as the method is asynchronous).